# Custom localized BooleanConverter

Tags: c#, winforms, typeconverter, typedescriptor, propertydescriptor

I am trying to implement localized BooleanConverter. Everything works well so far, but when you **double click** on the property next message is being shown:

"Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Boolean'."

I suppose the problem is in method CreateInstance of TypeConverter which has that boolean property.

```
public class BoolTypeConverter : BooleanConverter
{
    private readonly string[] values = { Resources.BoolTypeConverter_False, Resources.BoolTypeConverter_True };

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string) && value != null)
        {
            var valueType = value.GetType();

            if (valueType == typeof(bool))
            {
                return values[(bool)value ? 1 : 0];
            }
            else if (valueType == typeof(string))
            {
                return value;
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var stringValue = value as string;

        if (stringValue != null)
        {
            if (values[0] == stringValue)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (values[1] == stringValue)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return new StandardValuesCollection(values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of your code is you are overriding [`GetStandardValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d5c913f(v=vs.110).aspx) incorrectly.

In fact you don't need to override `GetStandardValues`, just remove it and you will get expected result, that acts like original boolean converter while showing your desired strings:

[image]

When overriding `GetStandardValues` you should return a list of supported values of the type that you are creating converter for, then using the `ConvertTo` you provide string representation values and using `ConvertFrom`, provide a way to converting the type from string values.